# Code in Beginning Android Games book giving error

Tags: android, button

I'm a newbie to android development and i was reading the code for creating a custom button which tells u the no of times u clicked tht button. The code is as follows:

```
package com.helloworld;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button button;

    int touchCount;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        button=new Button(this);
        button.setText("Click Me");
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        setContentView(button);
    }
    public void onCLick(View v)
    {
        touchCount++;
    button.setText("touched me"+touchCount+"time(s)");
    }
}
```

THE ERROR :

```
The type HelloWorldActivity must implement the inherited abstract method      View.OnClickListener.onClick(View) - Breakpoint:HelloWorldActivity
```

I looked in a couple of sites and tried something but nothing worked. Please help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

It should be `onClick`, not `onCLick` (lower case l).

Answer (score 2):

Your HelloWorldActivity is acting as (or implementing) a `View.OnClickListener`.  As an OnClickListener Java is expecting you implement the method "onClick".  Java is case sensitive and interprets `onClick` is different from `onCLick` (where you have a capital L rather then the expected lower case).  Try updating your onClick to a lower l.